# Admob ad unit IDs

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated admob in my application which has 44 activities, so I created 44 ad unit. When I use this ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 test id, my application is working properly. But when I change the IDs to the real ones, it force closes on open. Should/Can I use only one ID for all the 44 ad units, because I think that it is the problem?

Comment: Yes, you can use one Ad unit ID for all your banner ads and one Ad unit ID for all your interstitial ads, if you have any. I doubt this is the issue for your application crashing though.